# How to use two kinds of footnotes?

Tags: footnotes

I'd like to use two kinds of footnotes : arabic and alpha. I've just tried to use the following command : `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}`, but it affects the entire document. How can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if you want the footnotes numbered throughout the document or per page, but the manyfoot package will allow you to do either. The commands below were used (in the book documentclass) to add an additional set of footnotes, using symbols, with the second set of footnotes resetting on each page.

```
\usepackage[perpage]{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[fnsymbol]
```

The commands for the new set(s) of footnotes you define are \footnoteA and/or \footnoteB.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works the way I was searching for. @Susan : I'll use it throughout the document.

Answer (score 8):

Using `manyfoot`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[arabic]
\setlength{\textheight}{4cm}
\begin{document}
  Here\footnoteA{Alpha foot note} and there\footnoteB{arabic foot note}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `nccfoots`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccfoots}
\setlength{\textheight}{4cm}
\begin{document}
  Here\Footnote{a}{Alpha foot note} and there\Footnote{1}{arabic foot note}
\end{document}
```